# Is there an Intent for READ_ALOUD action in GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to read some text to the user, just like it's possible in Mirror API. Is that possible in Google Glass GDK via Intent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an intent, but you can use the Android [`TextToSpeech`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) class for this purpose. Essentially, just create an instance of `TextToSpeech` and then call the `speak` method with the string you want it to speak.

There is some initialization overhead involved with the TTS engine so you should try to do it early — you may experience a delay if you try to initialize the engine at the exact moment that you want it to speak.

The `CompassService` class in the GDK Compass sample shows this in more detail.

Comment: Here's a link to the CompassService class if anyone is interested: https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/compass/CompassService.java